# Error with opening and reading a binary file: "argumentexception was unhandled, stream was not readable"

Tags: vb.net

Imports System.IO

Module Module1

```
 Structure student
     Dim studentname As String
     Dim rollnumber As String
     Dim studentclass As String
 End Structure

 'Structure writing

 ' End Structure

 ' Structure reading

 'End Structure
 Sub Main()
     Dim newstudent As student
     newstudent.studentname = "DDD"
     newstudent.rollnumber = "123"
     newstudent.studentclass = "AS"

     Dim studentstream As New FileStream("C:\Users\___\Desktop\A2Filing.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)

     Dim bw As New BinaryWriter(studentstream)
     studentstream.Position = 33
     bw.Write(newstudent.studentname)
     bw.Write(newstudent.rollnumber)
     bw.Write(newstudent.studentclass)

     bw.Close()
     studentstream.Close()


     Dim br As New BinaryReader(studentstream)
     studentstream.Position = 11
     newstudent.studentname = br.ReadString
    newstudent.rollnumber = br.ReadString
     newstudent.studentclass = br.ReadString

     Console.WriteLine(newstudent.studentname)
     Console.WriteLine(newstudent.rollnumber)
     Console.WriteLine(newstudent.studentclass)

     br.Close()

     Console.ReadKey()
 End Sub
```

Problem is that its not letting me declare the binary reader the error still says

> the stream was not readable

Even when I tried declaring a new filestream with a different variable, I tried putting the reading and writing in different structures and it gave me this:

> non shared members in a structure cannot be declared "new"

(when I tried declaring a "new" filestream")

> array bounds cannot appear in type specifier

(when I tried giving it the file location)

> declaration expected

(when I tried declaring binary writer, it said that studentstream hasnt been declared even though it was declared just 2 lines above)

Comment: The reader is trying to read from a closed FileStream.  It was closed by the bw.Close() call.  Also pretty murky what you hope to find back at Position 11.  This kind of random access can only work correctly if the file contains records of a fixed size.  Your data is not, strings have a variable size.  You'll have to re-think this.

Comment: oh thank you it started working. I have put data in the file and all of them are of a fixed length so thats not a issue (rollnumber/name/class all combined take 11 bytes). And can you please explain to me why binarywriter has to be open when all im trying to do is read data from a file?

Comment: It doesn't have to be open, the FileStream has to be open.  A class like BinaryWriter (like all stream classes in .NET) takes ownership of the stream you pass it.  So when you call bw.Close(), you'll also close the FileStream.  Just don't call Close().

Comment: oh alright, i thought that the filestream would close when I sent the studentstream.close command, not the bw.close one. Thanks again for helping me!

Comment: @HansPassant,  Umm.. its not the bw.close that's the problem it's the 
     studentstream.Close() line right after it.